# Merge files with ID before underscore

Tags: bash, cat

I am looking for a way to merge files that that same ID before the first undescore in the filename. The output should contain the ID only, followed by the fastq.gz. The output must be gzipped.

in

```
0394_L007_R1.fastq.gz 
0394_L008_R1.fastq.gz 
0444_L005_R1.fastq.gz 
0444_L006_R1.fastq.gz
```

out

```
0394.fastq.gz
0444.fastq.gz
```

Something more convenient than:

```
cat 0394_L007_R1.fastq.gz  0394_L008_R1.fastq.gz   > 0394.fastq.gz
```

Comment: cat combines files, rights? I would like to merge them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop that keeps appending to the target file. So it's really just a matter of finding the correct "target file" for current file and appending to it.

```
#! /bin/bash
for x in *.fastq.gz; do
     currid=$(echo "$x" | cut -d'_' -f1)
     cat "$x" >> "$currid".fastq.gz
done
```

Comment: however, it seems to run

Comment: @user2300940 Yes, I didn't log anything to the console. But I think it should do the job of merging. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: No new output files were created..?

Comment: That's odd. What shell do you use? I just ran this with a `#! /bin/bash` hashbang and it worked for me. I have bash 4.2.46 btw.

Comment: ubuntu based terminal

Comment: Did you try adding the bash hashbang at the top? I've updated my answer to add it now.

Answer (score 2):

First, collect the unique identifiers in an associative array:

```
declare -A ids
for f in *.fastq.gz; do
  ids[${f%%_*}]=1
done
```

Then use `gzcat` to pipe the (uncompressed) contents of each
matching file to `gzip` to recompress the output into a single file.

```
for id in "${!ids[@]}"; do
  gzcat "$id"_*.fastq.gz | gzip -c > "$id".fastq.gz
done
```

(Or, because I forgot that concatenated Gzip files are themselves valid Gzip files,

```
for id in "${!ids[@]}"; do
  cat "$id"_*.fastq.gz > "$id".fastq.gz
done
```

)

Comment: I had the wrong array name (fixed now), but I'm not sure how that could have caused a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple command:

ls | tr '_' '.' | cut -d'.' -f1,4,5 | uniq

Comment: OP said they want to merge files. I believe this only merges the file names.